# what is .motn file?

Tags: flash, video

In a flash based project, i got a few files with extension as ".motn". I am not sure what this file is or more importantly, with what editor/tool i can work on this file. What i guess is this might be a way to create flv movies, out of pictures , vectors and otehr data, but it's just a guess.So, basically i have two doubts:
1. what is a .motn file
2. How /with what tool can i work on a .motn file efficiently.

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the '.motn' file extension is short for a 'motion' file which is also software developed by Apple.

http://www.apple.com/finalcutstudio/motion/